# Azure web application how to show error message

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-storage, azure-worker-roles

I am developing an web application on Azure, on occurrence of exception I want to display an error message to the User on a custom error page.

What is the best practice, I don't want to use Session to store the Exception.

Currently, I am using Azure diagnostics to log the error in Logs Table and Events Table and Session to Store the exception detail under Global.asax.cs (app_error) event

And using the Session in Error page to display the error.

Sorry the question is much of basic..any inputs would be helpful..

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you’re using a custom ASP.NET error page? In this case, you can use HttpServerUtility.GetLastError to get the exception. Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.getlasterror.aspx for a sample.

Same thread from you in MSDN forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/df31d683-81a9-4527-9109-94e57ff528f1

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have provide, I am sure you are developing an ASP.NET Web Role and want to display custom error page in an event of exception. You can use ASP.NET Built in Custom Error Page functionality to display custom error page with hand crafted exception details and message on it.

At Page Level you can use the Page_Error event handler by implementing the Page_Error method on all of your pages.

At Application Level, you can use Application_Error handler to trap exceptions/errors by defining  Application_Error method  in  Global.asax page.

At Global Level, you can handle exceptions/errors by adding custom errors setting in web.config as below: